# Animate react functional component when unmounted or destroyed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

How can I animate a component will unmount? I tried to use a reference to change styles before unmounting it, but the reference is lost when the component will unmounted, I also tried to use react transition group but it didn't work.

TaskItem.component.jsx

```
import React, { useRef, memo, useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group'; // ES6
import "./TaskItem.css"
//STYLES

const DIV = styled.div`

    padding: ${
        props => "12px 15px"
    };

    overflow: hidden;
`;

const TR = styled.tr`
    background-color: ${
        (props) => {

            return props.index % 2 === 0 ? '#f3f3f3': '#ffffff'

            

        }
    };
   

    border-bottom: ${
        props => "1px solid #dddddd"
    };;

    transition: visibility 0.5s;

    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #009879;
    }
`;

function TaskItem({ task, index, tasks }) {

    const ref = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(ref) // null :(
        return () => {
            console.log('animate component')
        }
    }, [])

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const toggleDoneTask = task => dispatch({ type: "DONE_TASK", task })

    const deleteTask = task => dispatch({type: "DELETE_TASK", task})

    return (
        <CSSTransition classNames="example"
        timeout={5000} in={task.done == false}>
        <TR ref={ref} tasks={tasks} task={task} index={index}>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {task.title}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {task.description}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV  done={task.done}>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        checked={task.done}
                        onChange={() => toggleDoneTask(task)}
                        style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    />

                    <button style={{marginLeft: "10px"}} onClick={() => deleteTask(task)}> X </button>
                </DIV>
            </td>
        </TR>
        </CSSTransition>    
    )
}

export default TaskItem
```

TaskItem.css

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
}
```

Tasks.component.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector} from "react-redux";
import TaskItem from "./TaskItem";
import styles from "./Tasks.css";

function Tasks() {

  const {tasks, showDoneTasks} = useSelector(state => state)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>learning react </h1>
      <table className={styles.table}>
        <thead>
          <tr className={styles.tr}>
            <th className={styles.th}>Title</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>Description</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>Done</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            showDoneTasks.show ? 
            tasks.map((task, index) => {
              return <TaskItem
                tasks={tasks}
                index={index}
                task={task}
                key={task.id}
                >
              </TaskItem>
            })
            :
            tasks.filter(t => !t.done).map((task, index) => {
              return <TaskItem
                tasks={tasks}
                index={index}
                task={task}
                key={task.id}
                >
              </TaskItem>
            })
          
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Tasks;
```

IGNORE: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: totally add boolean state to your component on clean up function of lifecycle make it true . use that on your JSS.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, I'm new in react

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using ref. If I understand correctly, you should wrap the element you want to animate with `CSSTransition`.

Comment: I already did, but it didn't work.